# Transforming in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this class

```
    data class IntersectionWithWorkSpaceWidgetFeed(
        @Embedded
        val workSpace: WorkSpace,
        @Embedded
        val widget: WidgetMetaData,
        @Embedded
        val feed: Feed
)
```

Now this is returned from a 3 way many to many join between 3 columns

So the relation is like this workspace has many to many relation with widget and widget has many to many with relation with Feed

From DB I get

```
 List<IntersectionWithWorkSpaceWidgetFeed>
```

In which  each row has repeated Worksapce and one widget and one feed

eg

```
Worspace(1) Widget(A) Feed(2)
Worspace(1) Widget(A) Feed(3)
Worspace(1) Widget(B) Feed(3)
Worspace(1) Widget(B) Feed(2)
```

I was wondering if this can be transformed to this POJO

```
data class MergedData(
        @Embedded
        val workSpace: WorkSpace,
        @Embedded
        val widget: List<WidgetData>,
        @Embedded
        val feed: List<Feed>
)
```

which maintains the relationship as shown above.
Any nudge in the right direction will be greatly appreciated

**Edit**

This data

```
List<IntersectionWithWorkSpaceWidgetFeed>
```

I am getting from Room Data Base , however I want to understand if that can be transformed after I receive it from Room using Kotlin Transformation.

Just to be clear , I am NOT looking to return

```
 data class MergedData(
            @Embedded
            val workSpace: WorkSpace,
            @Embedded
            val widget: List<WidgetData>,
            @Embedded
            val feed: List<Feed>
    )
```

directly from ROOM.

Comment: I presume this question is related to Room? If so I would recommend adding the tag and [edit]ing your question to make this clear.

Comment: Yes ,however I am looking for the transformation after I get the data from DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

```
data class Workspace(val id: String)
data class Widget(val id: String)
data class Feed(val id: String)

data class RawData(
    val workspace: Workspace, 
    val widget: Widget, 
    val feed: Feed
)

data class MergedData(
    val workspace: Workspace, 
    val widgets: List<Widget>, 
    val feeds: List<Feed>
)

val raw = listOf(
    RawData(workspace = Workspace("1"), widget = Widget("A"), feed = Feed("2")),
    RawData(workspace = Workspace("1"), widget = Widget("A"), feed = Feed("3")),
    RawData(workspace = Workspace("1"), widget = Widget("B"), feed = Feed("3")),
    RawData(workspace = Workspace("1"), widget = Widget("B"), feed = Feed("2"))
)
```

You could do something like this:

```
val result: MergedData = 
    raw
        // First find the distinct workspaces
        .distinctBy { it.workspace.id }

        // Transform the results into just the workspaces
        .map { it.workspace }

        // Create a map of Workspace -> List<Widget> and List<Feed>
        .associateWith { workspace ->
            val rows = raw.filter { it.workspace.id == workspace.id }

            Pair(rows.map { it.widget }, rows.map { it.feed })
        }

        // Transform the map into the target "MergedData" type
        .map { entry ->
            MergedData(
                workspace = entry.key, 
                widgets = entry.value.first, 
                feeds = entry.value.second
            )
        }
```

This will, however, produce duplicate `Widget` and `Feed` instances within a given `Workspace`, but I'm sure you figure out how to resolve that if it's indeed a problem.

Comment: After getting the distinct workspaces i added the widgets in the list and created the merged data object . Thanks